# Validation regex for name to accept dot or space only after a letter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

Regex for firstname and lastname I have included given

```
  validates :first_name, :last_name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z\. ]+\z/ }
```

It accepts firstname like Mr. A Ayer but it also accepts  . john I want validation something it would accept . or space only after aletter. Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
\A[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\. ]*\z
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/32

Comment: It should accept dot or space only after a letter, your regex accepts anything that starts with a letter.

Comment: @Borsunho mm then lets wait for OP to throw some light over it

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 /\A([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][\. ])+\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-z][\s\.]|[A-z])+
```

Check with this regex